# "Mongo Error : Authentication failed" can't read datas from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Today I wanted to use clusters in MongoDB Atlas to get an online DB, instead of my MongoDB local database (which worked perfectly fine),**

So, I followed a mLab tutorial,

It works perfectly on writing in the database (when I auth in my website, it adds the datas in the database, when I write a message in the chat it adds the message, etc...)

But when I want to read these datas, I got :

```
MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

MongoError: Authentication failed
```

The connect in my server/index.js seems to work, because I got the console log :

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.USER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  ).then(() =>
    console.log(
      "working"
    )
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

but not other routes, like this one (which get all users in the database) :

```
const mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

router.get("/getAll", function(req, res) {
  console.log("get all users");
  const client = new mongo(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.USER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
  client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("users");
    collection.find().toArray((err, items) => {
      res.json(items);
    });
    client.close();
  });
});
```

One model from Mongoose :

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  sexe: String,
  mobilePhone: String,
  departement: Number,
  city: String,
  moviesLiked: Array,
  seriesLiked: Array,
  moviesDisliked: Array,
  seriesDisliked: Array,
  moviesFavorites: Array,
  seriesFavorites: Array,
  lists: Array,
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  lastConnection: Date,
  isVerified: Boolean,
  isAdmin: Boolean,
  isModerator: Boolean,
  isConnected: Boolean
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I can show you the code of other files if needed, or give you the link of the repo if someone wants it, but it's a really big project,

Thanks,

Comment: As I see from your connection string you are not using mLab, but using mongodb atlas. Also why do you both mongoose.connect and MongoClient.connect?

Comment: yes sorry I wanted to say mongoDB Atlas, because mLab is close to all new accounts, and to connect mongoDB in a route, I need to do it another time no?

Comment: Just use mongoose.connect in your main file (index.js, app.js) and there is no need to connect in your routes.

Comment: ok but how do I do queries inside the routes please?

Comment: One more important thing in MongoDB Atlas whitelist Your IP address, so that you can send request from your Device.

Comment: Do you have already mongoose models? Or do you want use native mongodb package?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes I do have mongoose models that I require like this (for a user): let User = require("../../models/User");

Comment: Are they mongoose model? Can you add one of them to the question?

Comment: I just added one model in the question above, and i require the model with let User = require("../../models/User");

Comment: Ok I will post an answer

Comment: Have you applied readWriteRole to your Atlas DB user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to connect mongodb with both mongoose.connect() and MongoClient.connect(), one of them will be enough.

If you want to use mongoose you can connect to mongodb in your main file (index.js or app.js), and when connected to the db your server can start listening.
And you don't need to connect mongodb in your routes.

For example:

index.js (main file)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

const users = require("../routes/users"); //todo: correct the users route path

app.use("/api/users", users);

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.USER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("working"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

in your route: (users.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../../models/User");

router.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find({});

  res.send(users);
});

module.exports = router;
```

As you see there is no connection related code in our route, because we have already connected when the application starts.

For this code to work, you need to add your local IP to the IP whitelist IP  in mongodb atlas panel. (SECURITY --> Network Access --> IP Whitelist.

Also the user you are using to connect must have read an write priveleges. 
You can check your users priveleges in SECURITY --> Database Access --> MongoDB Users.

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, now I have to do this for all the routes, thank you so much !

Comment: @Versifiction  I am happy that it worked, now your routes will be much less code:)

Comment: You can also uninstall mongodb package now as it is not used anymore.

Comment: ok, I just got again the "authentication failed", but I think it's because I have to clean many things, I clean, and I tell you if there's something wrong again :)

Comment: @Versifiction  copy the connection url from mongodb atlas panel and replace your password, it will be ok

Comment: they say my mongodb atlas url is : mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@ofilms-demo-f9iwz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
so I put my password and username in environment variables, as you can see in the question hm

Comment: @Versifiction do you have the same user in your env file as in the mongodb atlas panel connection string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201792/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-versifiction).